# Laravel 5.3 Constraining Eager Loads not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have two model `User` and `Profile` in one to one relationship.

I want to retrieve all user where `profile.status == TRUE` using following code.

```
$users = User::with(['profile' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('status', TRUE);
    }])->get();


    dd(count($users)); //50
```

I have 50 users and only among of them only 3 has `status == TRUE`. But always it display **50**.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting 50 users because you are applying condition to `profile`. `dd($user->profile)` you will get only the records of the profile whose status is true.

Use `whereHas()`:

```
$users = User::whereHas('profile', function ($query) {
        $query->where('status', TRUE);
    })->get();

dd(count($users));
```

Comment: But, there is a problem. Arise  N + 1 query problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it work with single Query, you can use Query Builder `join` like

```
\DB::table('users')->join('profile', function ($join){
                        $join->on('users.id', '=', 'profile.user_id')->where('profile.status', '=',TRUE);
                    })->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, finally i move status column to users table and use Model ORM query and its working.

Answer (score 0):

You said you're having N+1 problem, so you need to use both `whereHas()` and `with()` like this to get users with profiles and to solve N+1 problem:

```
$users = User::whereHas('profile', function ($query) {
        $query->where('status', TRUE);
    })
    ->with('profile')
    ->get();
```