# Laravel Nested Relationship Where 5.5 Return All Records

Tags: laravel

I'm having some trouble when trying to fetch records from database. Here's the table schema:

```
users
--------------
id
username
password
email

divisions
--------------
id
name

employee
--------------
name
birth_date
status
class
division_id
user_id

projects
--------------
id
title
body
user_id
```

So, for the relationship explanations:

[relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0rsN.jpg)

Okay, i'm trying to fetch project based on division_id on table **employee** with the following code:

```
# query code
$division_id = 10;

$items = Project::with(['user.employee.division' => function($query) use ($division_id) {
            $query->where('id', $division_id);
}])->get();
```

I've added the required belongsTo, hasMany or hasOne to the models.

```
# User.php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Employee', 'user_id');
    }
    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Project', 'user_id');
    }
}

# Division.php
class Division extends Model
{
    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Employee', 'division_id');
    }
}

# Employee
class Employee extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }

    public function division()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Division', 'division_id');
    }
}

# Project.php
class Project extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

**So, what's the problem?**

Here's the thing, when i run the query code i'm getting all the records and the division object on employe relationship returning null.

If anyone thinks my code is wrong, please enlighten me.

Thanks.

Comment: What output you are expecting as it states give me all users and their projects under division 10.

Comment: When i run the query code, where clause on division_id didn't work. The result returning users and their projects under all divisions without being filtered. Is it possible because the environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some digging, i found an answer. The query code should change to **whereHas**:

```
# query code
$division_id = 10;

$items = App\Project::whereHas('user.employee.division',
    function($query) use ($division_id) {
        $query->where('divisions.id', $division_id);
    })
    ->with(['user.employee.division']) // N+1 problem
    ->get();
```

reference: [Laravel 5.3 Constraining Eager Loads not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40797538/laravel-5-3-constraining-eager-loads-not-working)